How can I use VBA to generate an SVG exact pipeline sketch that is similar to the pipeline KML file by using x and y coordinates of the pipeline
I have a pipeline in google earth that has been exported into excel and has several x and y coordinates. The x and y coordinates are different points on the pipeline. Basically all the x and y coordinates make up the pipeline.
Can someone help with writing a vba code that can generate an svg sketch of the pipeline with the known x and y coordinates ? I have tried a few times but my svg sketch returns an empty file.
These are the x and y coordinates I am using:

this is the code i initially tried
Sub PlotPipeline()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x_coords() As Variant
    Dim y_coords() As Variant
    Dim svg_code As String
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    
    ' Open the workbook containing the pipeline data
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to the actual sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Resize the arrays to hold the coordinates
    ReDim x_coords(1 To lastRow - 1)
    ReDim y_coords(1 To lastRow - 1)
    
    ' Extract x and y coordinates from the worksheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        x_coords(i - 1) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        y_coords(i - 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i
    
    ' Create SVG code
    svg_code = "<svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""0 0 500 500"">" & vbCrLf
    
    ' Add lines representing the pipeline
    For i = LBound(x_coords) To UBound(x_coords) - 1
        svg_code = svg_code & "    <line x1=""" & x_coords(i) & """ y1=""" & y_coords(i) & """ x2=""" & x_coords(i + 1) & """ y2=""" & y_coords(i + 1) & """ stroke=""black"" stroke-width=""2"" />" & vbCrLf
    Next i
    
    ' Close SVG tag
    svg_code = svg_code & "</svg>"
    
    ' Debug: Display SVG code
    MsgBox svg_code
    
    ' Open a new text file and write the SVG code
    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open "pipeline.svg" For Output As #fileNum
    Print #fileNum, svg_code
    Close #fileNum
    
    MsgBox "SVG file generated successfully!"
    
End Sub


Open "pipeline.svg" For Output As #fileNum try using the full path to the file and not just the name.
